# how can i solve unity android build error 104

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

```
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 104 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in <bccb16a88ec4456dbf07978c418f407b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <bccb16a88ec4456dbf07978c418f407b>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Why is this happens and how can i solve this?

Comment: This is not error 104, this is telling you that there are a total of 104 errors (number of errors not error code)

Comment: @Jimmar so....... how can i solve this?

Comment: I dunno .. you are telling me that you have some errors, you did not provide what the errors are.